# HTML form name = session

Tags: php, html, forms, input, session-variables

I pass an individual filename as a session to my HTML form name. My first code prints a list of the files in my directory "diary", and I am trying to print the contents of the chosen file in a new page readpage.html
But to my horror, since I am passing the session $_SESSION['filename'] as a variable, all my buttons direct me to the last file that my session variable has been assigned to.

What can I do so that each button passes the a different filename? I have found it impossible to pass a php variable as my form input name, since $variable = $_POST[PHP VARIABLE] doesn't work..

note) I'm trying to achieve this by using PHP only (no javascript, mysql tables etc)
Thank you

```
$folder = "diary";
    $files = scandir($folder);
    $fName = "diary/$file";
    ?><form method="POST" action="readPage.html"><?
    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        if($file != "." && $file != "..")
        {
            $_SESSION["file"] = $file;
            $data = file_get_contents("diary/$file");
            $info = explode("\t",$data);
            ?>
                <input type="radio" name = <?=$_SESSION["file"] ?> >
                <?=$info[0]?> <input type="submit" value = "Go"  ><br>
            <?
        }
    }
    ?></form><?
```

Receving file readpage.html

```
    echo $_SESSION["file"];
    $fOpen = "diary/".$_SESSION["file"];
    $fData = file_get_contents($fOpen);
```

Comment: This is wrong `action="readPage.html"` - Unless you've instructed Apache to treat `.html` as PHP, rename it to `.php`. Plus, don't forget to slap in `session_start();` if you haven't already.

Comment: I have set session_start()
I don't understand why action should be readpage.php and not readpage.html, it's never really gave me any problems :/ excuse my ignorance

Comment: Alright, so you've instructed Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP, correct?

Comment: My current server sets so by default; but I'll keep it in mind. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You opened up a php segment here with

> < ?, when it should be < ?php

this

> ? > < form method="POST" action="readPage.html" > < ?php

not this

> ? > < form method="POST" action="readPage.html" > < ?

Comment: How do you know OP doesn't have short tags set?

Comment: I have short tags set, but I see why it could be a problem in the future. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use session. Instead of $_SESSION["file"] use $_POST["file"]. I added name attribute name="file" to your input and as value attribute I added file name. In processing page you can accesss file name in variable $_POST["file"].

```
$folder = "diary";
$files = scandir($folder);
$fName = "diary/$file";
?><form method="POST" action="readPage.html"><?
foreach ($files as $file)
{
    if($file != "." && $file != "..")
    {
        $data = file_get_contents("diary/$file");
        $info = explode("\t",$data);
        ?>
            <input type="radio" name="file" value="<? echo $file ?>" >
            <?=$info[0]?> <input type="submit" value = "Go"  ><br>
        <?
    }
}
?></form><?
```

To process form:

```
echo $_POST["file"];
$fOpen = "diary/".$_POST["file"];
$fData = file_get_contents($fOpen);
```

Of course you should change form action to php script readPage.html to readPage.php